# How does one show Caratheodory's criterion for e.g. counting measure?

Tags: measure-theory

How does one show Caratheodory's criterion for e.g. counting measure?

I think it's intuitive since every $E \subset X$ can be written for $A \subset X$ like:

$E=(A \cap E) \cup (E \setminus A)$

And then the counting measure on this intuitively must satisfy the criterion.

But is this sufficient for proof?

Comment: If we start with the [counting measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure) as outer measure $m*$ then it is easy to prove that every set is $m*$-measurable (i.e. all sets satisfy the Caratheodory criterion). This shows that it can be looked at as a measure on $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal P(X)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $E$ is infinite, then one of $A\cap E, E\setminus A$ must be infinite and we get something like $\infty=\infty+..$. On the other hand, if $E$ is finite, then it's just a matter of counting because $A\cap E, E\setminus A$ are both finite and disjoint and the cardinality of $E$ is the sum of cardinalities of $A\cap E, E\setminus A$.

Comment: What you mean "a matter of counting"?

Comment: @mavavilj I have edited it

Answer (score 0):

Personally, without going too crazy with details, I'd say that Carathéodory establishes that a set $E$ is $\mu^*$-measurable if and only if $\mu^*(A)\ge\mu^*(A\cap E)+\mu^*(A\setminus E)$ for all $A$ such that $\mu^*(A)<\infty$.

Since by all means $\mu^*(S)=\begin{cases}\lvert S\rvert&\text{if }\lvert S\rvert<\aleph_0\\ \infty&\text{if }\lvert S\rvert\ge\aleph_0\end{cases}$ and certainly $\lvert A\rvert+\lvert B\rvert=\lvert A\rvert+\lvert A\cap B\rvert$ for finite sets $A$, $B$, we end up having, for all $E$ and for all $A$ of finite outer measure, $$\mu^*(A\cap E)+\mu^*(A\setminus E)=\mu^*(A)$$